# How to make transactions with paypal in windows phone 8 app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, paypal

I am working on restaurant app in which i need to make transactions with Paypal account in windows phone 8. Customer pays the bill by entering his login details and pays through Paypal. How to do this in C# ?

Comment: Looked at projects such as https://github.com/paypal/Windows8SDK ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link on how to implement PayPal API's into your C# Windows 8 phone application:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/windows-8-checkout-sdk/gs_win8xo/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the PayPal Windows 8 SDK has been discontinued.

According to the [Paypal Developer Website](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/windows-8-checkout-sdk/gs_win8xo/):

Important: The PayPal Windows 8 SDK has been discontinued. Deployed applications will no longer be supported starting June 17th, 2016. In addition, all related documentation will be removed from this site on the same date. Consult PayPal Developer documentation for alternate integration options.